# Enable the jQuery code below to execute after onClick event anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the snippet of code below to pause a slider (slider revolution):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".rev_slider_wrapper").each(function(){
    $this = jQuery(this);
    id_array = $this.attr("id").split("_");
    id = id_array[2];
    jQuery.globalEval( 'revapi'+id+'.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e)      {revapi'+id+'.revpause();});' );
  });
});
```

How do I make the snippet below to execute only after a click event anywhere on the page?

```
jQuery(".rev_slider_wrapper").each(function(){
  $this = jQuery(this);
  id_array = $this.attr("id").split("_");
  id = id_array[2];
  jQuery.globalEval( 'revapi'+id+'.revresume();' );
});
```

Comment: a click anywhere on the page? `$(document).on('click', function() {
    // The code
});`

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoS. You should have made it an answer! :)

Comment: maybe i should write the answer, so the question will be in the "answered" state? I don't know the rules about writing again something, just let me know (you or one moderator :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this inside your `$(document).ready()` function:

```
$("body").click(function(){
  //your code snippet
});
```

If `body` does not work try things like `document` or `html`